# Bitcoind randomly stops downloading the blockchain

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

I have bitcoind running from a 2 GB CentOS 6 box in order to check balances of addresses. The problem is that it just randomly stops downloading the blockchain sometimes, and I have to use ./bitcoind stop and ./bitcoind to start it back up again.

./bitcoind getinfo gives me:

```
{
    "version" : 90201,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 213322,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 14,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 3370181.79927784,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1410016320,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

Comment: Anything useful in debug.log?

Comment: I'll post it when the bitcoind stops again

Comment: There were a few other questions that suggested similar problems, but it seems like they may be hard to track down without a debugger, a developer's knowledge, and access to a system where the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: By the way, as far as installing it to check address balances: Bitcoin Core currently does not support checking the balances of arbitrary addresses, only those that are in your wallet and for which you have the private key.  So if that was your goal, you will need to find a different solution.